# Ansible: Iterating through multiple separate lists

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to add a proxy to Zabbix server using the ansible-zabbix module

I have vars that collect IP addresses/hostnames of servers/proxies/agents

I need to go to each zabbix server and add all the proxies that I have.

I tried several different "with_XXX" loops, none of them seems to work.
Environment: CentOS7, Ansible2.8, Python2.7, Zabbix4.2

```
---
- name: Install and configure Zabbix Proxy + Agent
  hosts: zabbix-proxy
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
   proxy_env:
     http_proxy: proxy_used_in_different_tasks
     https_proxy: proxy_used_in_different_tasks
   servervars:
     ip: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}" # server nodes IPs as a comma delimited string, for configs
     ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # server nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
     hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #server nodes hostnames as a list
   proxyvars:
     ip: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}" # proxy nodes IPs as a comma delimited string, for configs
     ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # proxy nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
     hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #proxy nodes hostnames as a list
   agentvars:
     ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-agent-only'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # agent nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
     hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-agent-only'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #agent nodes hostnames as a list

  tasks:
### below works fine - shows all facts I need
    - debug:
        msg:
        - TEST 1
        - "{{ servervars }}"
        - TEST 2
        - "{{ proxyvars }}"
        - TEST 3
        - "{{ agentvars }}"

    - name: Create proxies on the server
      local_action:
        module: zabbix_proxy
        server_url: "http://{{ item.0.hostname }}.net.local"
        login_user: Admin
        login_password: zabbix
        proxy_name: "{{ item.1.hostname }}"
        description: Proxy
        status: active
        state: present
        interface:
            type: 0
            main: 1
            useip: 0
            ip: "{{ item.1.ip_list }}"
            dns: "{{ item.1.hostname }}"
            port: 10050
      with_list:
        - "{{ servervars }}"
        - "{{ proxyvars }}"
```

Expected: to create a proxy on the server (current setup is 1xServer, 1xProxy, 2xAgent as test env)

Actual result: mostly I get the error:

```
"FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/proxy.yml': line 41, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Create proxies in the server\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: dict object has no element 0"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked

I substituted `with_XXX` with a nested `loop`, but I also changed my variables structure a bit

The final version looks like this:

```
---
- name: Install and configure Zabbix Proxy + Agent
  hosts: zabbix-proxy
  become: true
  vars:
   proxy_env:
     http_proxy: proxy_used_in_different_tasks
     https_proxy: proxy_used_in_different_tasks
   allvars:
     servervars:
       ip: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}" # server nodes IPs as a comma delimited string, for configs
       ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # server nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
       hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-server'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #server nodes hostnames as a list
     proxyvars:
       ip: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}" # proxy nodes IPs as a comma delimited string, for configs
       ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # proxy nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
       hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-proxy'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #proxy nodes hostnames as a list
     agentvars:
       ip_list: "{{ groups['zabbix-agent-only'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list }}" # agent nodes IPs as a list, for ansible
       hostname: "{{ groups['zabbix-agent-only'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') | list }}" #agent nodes hostnames as a list

  tasks:
    - name: Create proxies in the server
      local_action:
        module: zabbix_proxy
        server_url: "http://{{ item.0 }}.net.local/zabbix/"
        login_user: Admin
        login_password: zabbix
        proxy_name: "{{ item.1 }}"
        description: Proxy
        status: active
        state: present
        interface:
            type: 0
            main: 1
            useip: 0
            ip: "{{ item.2 }}"
            dns: "{{ item.1 }}"
            port: 10050
      loop: "{{ allvars.servervars.hostname|product(allvars.proxyvars.hostname, allvars.proxyvars.ip_list)|list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `with_nested` 
and not `with_list` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian

Comment: `with_nested` was not working for some reason
but I made it work with `loop` after reworking variables a bit (that helped for some reason)
I posted fixed playbook as a separate reply below